# How to use JBox2D debug-draw in Slick2D?

Tags: java, slick2d, jbox2d

[JBox2D](http://www.jbox2d.org/), the Java port of the Box2D physics engine, features an extensible module for creating debug drawing of shapes. How can I use this with the [Slick2D](http://slick2d.com) game library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [JBox2D DebugDraw class for Slick2D](https://gist.github.com/3074904) it is simple to add debug drawing. Put the below code in your `init` method:

```
Slick2DJBox2DDebugDraw debugDraw = new Slick2DJBox2DDebugDraw(gameContainer);
debugDraw.setFlags(DebugDraw.e_shapeBit);
world.setDebugDraw(debugDraw); // Where world is your JBox2D world
```

Comment: Great solution, but it doesn't take into account that objects may be smaller than 1 meter (currently drawing approximate shapes). It uses integers to draw objects position. I tried to adapt it to float values, but I can't seem to find out how the xIntsPool works.
It would be great of you could give some sort of guide/tip to do so, or an alternative solution.